# How to change height of an element as screen size gets smaller?

Tags: html, css

I am stumped on this issue. I have a feeling the solution is rather simple, but I can't figure it out myself.

Currently the background of one section doesn't increase its height to accommodate all the text that gets pushed down due to lower screen size. How do I make it so the background of 1 section increases together with the text.

I have made a gif of the action: https://i.gyazo.com/fb3a0ad686f28dfbb0f016810f3e9d0e.gif

And some relevant code: 
http://www.bootply.com/wXC2JnWXbT

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you provide fiddle on your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `height:auto` and setting a `min-height` along with it? Or add padding to the bottom so that you can have that initial gap still-- But that would make the text always have that padding, which I don't know that you want, so I wouldn't advise it.

Alternatively, set `overflow:auto` so that a scrollbar will appear when the text goes beyond its box. Then there's no need for height change

Comment: This guy! It worked perfectly! Thanks so much, I knew the solution would be so simple. I guess I just need to memorize all of CSS properties. Also, do you reckon I should do the same to all sections like this? Because there are about 6 more with different content. Better be safe than sorry? If It goes over the initial height amount, which is set to 100% currently.

Comment: If they're under different classes, then yes, you'll want to put them on the other classes.